# $this->form_validation->run() is return always false in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

First of all, i want to know that i am new in Codeigniter. I have a form with one field and submit button And checking validation.But, $this->form_validation->run() is giving false.
Here is my code:

`<body>
       <h3>Please give a valid website url!!!.</h3>
       <?php echo form_open('website/submission');  ?>
       <p><input type="text" name="website"></p>
       <p><input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Check Website"></p>
       <?php echo form_close();?>
   </body>`

And this is my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('u are not here');
class Website extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
       $this->load->view('form');
    }

    public function submission(){
        $formRules=array(
            array(
                'field'=> 'website' ,
                'label'=> 'Website Url',
                'rules'=>'required|minlength[3]|maxlength[10]'
            )
        );
         $this->form_validation->set_rules($formRules);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
           echo 'Failed';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Success';
        }
    }
}
```

Why it is giving always false, even i m typing "minimum 3 and maximum 4" letters in  textbox?

Comment: Which version of CI are you using?

Comment: Where are you loading form_validation library ?

Comment: Mr. Ross Wilson, I am using CI 3.

Comment: I am loading  form_validation  in autoload.php.

Comment: My Problem has been solved.  Just need to change in below line. $formRules['name']=array(
            array(
                'field'=> 'website' ,
                'label'=> 'Website Url',
                'rules'=>'required|minlength[3]|maxlength[10]'
            )
        );